# JavaScript slide menu toggle

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a toggle because for some reason the toggle function is not working.

this works as expected. it basically does the animation an a couple of css call then swaps classes for the next function call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".m-menu").click( function(){
if ($('.mobile-menu').hasClass("menu") ) {

        $(".mobile-menu").animate({left: '0'}, 500);
    $(".mobile-menu-bg").animate({left: '0'}, 500);
        $(".menu-close").css('display','inline');
        $(".menu-open").css('display','none');
        $( '.m-menu' ).removeClass( "m-menu" ).addClass("m-menu2");



 }



   });       
});
```

The next function looks like this, which is suppose to execute if the class is there, then switch back to the original class. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".m-menu2").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

if ($('.mobile-menu').hasClass("menu") ) {

          $(".mobile-menu").animate({left: '-200'}, 500);
          $(".mobile-menu-bg").animate({left: '-2000'}, 500);
          $(".menu-close").css('display','none');
          $(".menu-open").css('display','inline');
          $('.m-menu2').removeClass( "m-menu2" ).addClass("m-menu");
}

  });       
});
```

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle, codepen or plnkr we can help. Are you using jQuery and jQuery-UI? Which toggle function do you use?

Comment: it performs the first set code, then it doesn't listen to the other second part.

Comment: im using jQuery but it is not functioning properly..I am making the jsfiddle now

Comment: now It is doing nothing..but here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ved5gnllVt)

Comment: wait this is it [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tnX5/#&togetherjs=ved5gnllVt)

Comment: Your code is horribly messy and confused. You really should consider reformatting your entire project. I'd recommend restarting the entire thing, only including what you need and knowing *exactly* what each piece is doing

Comment: I am trying to understand what is going on here before I reformat my code